# How to Fetch Smarty Variables in PHP File?

Tags: php, smarty

I am display a smarty variable inside a php code, this is because i would like to compare something from Smarty into a PHP file.

Example:

```
<?php 

$ThisIsTheSmartyVariable

If ($ThisIsTheSmartyVariable == Something) {

Do Something

}

?>
```

This is the main idea but i dont understand it why its not working.

When i am trying to fetch all the variables its giving me this output:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function logactivity() in public_html/includes/smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1094

Let me know.